# I am getting BadPaddingException in my decrypt method

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

I am using the below (snippets) code to encrypt users' private data to store in a database, then decrypt so they can view it.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
String encrypted = new String(bytes);
```

This String is then stored in a database under a varchar column(s)

To decrypt:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
String decrypted = new String(bytes);[code]
```

Now seemingly randomly I get the occasional

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

Comment: A couple of things... First, it looks like you are encrypting passwords, which is a very poor idea.  Second, your code is insecure due to your use of ECB mode.  Use GCM or CBC with an HMAC.  Also, you define the cipher to use PKCS5Padding and then attempt to manually pad the result with the character 0...?  Why?  This is unnecessary.

Comment: Also don't use DES/3DES, use AES for new work.

Answer (score 3):

The data you get from encryption is **binary**. You can't safely convert your `byte[]` to `String` and back as you do, as not all the bytes have a 1-1 mapping back and forth. Either save you data in a field that can handle **binary data**, or encode your data using encodings that don't lose data like **base64** or **Hex** encoding.

Answer (score 1):

```
String encrypted = new String(bytes);
```

The problem is right here. `String` is not a container for binary data. Use `byte[]`, or hex- or base64-encode it if you must have a `String`.